# Custom Jackson Serializer for Top Level Map Type

Tags: java, json, serialization, jackson, deserialization

I have a "java" map  that I would like to serialize with my own custom serialization logic. Note that java map itself is the top-level object.

1. I want to output it as a collection rather than map only for above parameterized map type. All other map types should work as default (i.e. MyCustomObject could have Map which should work as usual).
2. I want to omit certain key/value from serialization based on some property value inside MyCustomObject.
3. MyCustomObject is already given to me and is not in my control.

Is there anyway to achieve this in jackson? Also, what about deserialization - in this case, I will want a map  back rather than collection.

Comment: By "custom `Map` type", you mean your own implementation of `Map`?

Comment: If your map type is an implementation of `Map`, the it is a simple case of extending `JsonSerializer<CustomerMapType>` and implementing the `serialize()` method. Deserialization is the same, but with `JsonDeserializer` and `deserialize()`. However, if your map is just a standard Map, then your (de)serializer classes will need to be for `MyCustomObject`. [Here's an example](https://ideone.com/Z5MYTW) of a joda `DateTime` serializer that makes it print seconds instead of milliseconds.

Comment: No this will be Java map only. I do not have my own map implementation. I have some knowledge of how to register my own serializer/deserializer for custom class using SimpleModule. I know know how to specify custom serializer if map is property of some class using @JsonSerialize(using = ""). However, I am not sure how to register my serializer/deserializer for parameterized java.util.Map class, which is top-level class.